# GNU GCC Codeblocks win32 function not declared

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

This is a snippet of code from a library in my project (Implot):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    t.S = _mkgmtime(ptm);

...

#ifdef _WIN32
  if (gmtime_s(ptm, &t.S) == 0)

...

#ifdef _WIN32
  if (localtime_s(ptm, &t.S) == 0)
```

and this project was just ported from Visual Studio 2019 to Codeblocks (C++17). For some reason this can't compile and I can't find anything online when I search up the error.

```
error '_mkgmtime' was not declared in this scope
error 'gmtime_s' was not declared in this scope
error 'localtime_s' was not declared in this scope
```

I understand that these errors are for missing functions, which is most likely due to a missing include file, however these have been used in Visual Studio 2019 with NO changes to any of the source code and it works fine there. Why isn't this working and how do I fix it?

Comment: First of all, are you building C or C++ code? C and C++ are two different languages, and have different functions. Case in point, C have a `gmtime_s` function since the C11 standard, but C++ does not have such a function.

Comment: C++. But if that is true, why does visual studio work fine then? Also how can I get it working on GCC?

Comment: While the C standard have many "safe" functions with the `_s` suffix, they were all added on behalf of Microsoft, and the Microsoft implementation doesn't always follow the standard anyway. Look at those functions as Microsoft (and Visual Studio compiler) specific.

Comment: Also Visual Studio tend to use an underscore prefix (as in `_mkgmtime`) for non-portable and non-standard functions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I can't find a substitute for `gmtime_s`. Also im not sure if `mktime` is the correct substitute for `_mkgmtime`?

Comment: How about plain `gmtime`?

Comment: `cannot convert 'tm*' to 'const time_t*'`. Not to mention it only has 1 parameter and the code is passing in 2 parameters

Comment: ? I can see that, it takes 1 parameter, but my code takes in 2 ported from msvc. My problem is how do I fix that.

Comment: Okay, then you have to use and check *compiler* specific macros instead of the more platform specific `_WIN32`.

Comment: Yes. In the question I said I looked up the errors for them, but I couldn't find anything. I was hoping that someone had this problem before and knew the solution/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the Visual Studio predefined macros documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-160) you can find compiler-specific macros which ben be used to identify if your code is being built by the Visual Studio C++ compiler.

For example the `_MSC_VER` macro, which you can check for instead of `_WIN32`.

As in:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
auto result = gmtime_s(ptm, &t.S);// Visual Studio
#else
auto result = gmtime(ptm);        // Anything else (like e.g. GCC)
#endif

if (result == nullptr) ...
```

Comment: Yep, that got it to compile! Thanks